# Does H2 Database support pessimistic locking?

Tags: locking, h2, mvcc

Does the [H2 Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) support pessimistic locking?

If so, how does its use interact with H2’s [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) implementation?

I'm not looking for advice on whether or not to use pessimistic locking. I have a specific need to emulate the behavior of another database that defaults to row-level pessimistic locking. I need to be able to test if a row is locked, and if not locked, lock it out from writes by any other database connection.